# How to add a image to a div element with a switch statement?

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

The idea is that every time life goes down by 1, one less image will show, or be in the div element later. The code is not finished, I'll add the rest of them later (5-1), but i want to see if it is possible first the way I'm doing it. Hopefully what I'm showing is enough to see what I'm trying to do.

```
function lifeloss() {
  life -= 1;
  var life = document.getElementById("lifecount");
  switch (life) {
    case 1:
      if (life >= 5) {
        life.innerHTML += "<img class="life" src="life.png">"
      }
      break;
    default:

  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how life could be >=5 in the case where life = 1.

Comment: @AlixBergeret It's like when you say your are 20 years old but are actually 25.

Comment: @AlixBergeret i have var life = 5 outside the function, that might be wrong of me though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`switch` statements are for concrete values. Since you're looking for a range (ie. `life >= 5`), you should settle for if/else statements:

```
function lifeloss() {
  life -= 1;
  var lifecount = document.getElementById("lifecount");

  if (life >= 5) {
    lifecount.innerHTML += '<img class="life" src="life.png" />';
  } else if (life >= 1) {
    //Perhaps a low life image?
  } else {
    //We're dead Jim
  }
}
```

After re-reading the question, if you're looking to COPY the image of life for each life, I recommend using [`string.repeat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```
function lifeloss() {
  life -= 1;
  var lifecount = document.getElementById("lifecount");

  var lifeImg = '<img class="life" src="life.png" />';

  lifecount.innerHTML = lifeImg.repeat(life);
}
```

Comment: I used the string.repeat() and now I'm not getting any console error, but the images is not showing up. Might be something in the rest of the code, or maybe i want to have the var life = 5 in the function aswell?

Comment: Inspect your lifecount element in the element inspector. Is `.innerHTML` being set correctly? Does `life.png` exist?

Comment: `console.log(life)` (Is it greater than 1?)

Comment: life.png does exist. Don't know what you mean by .innerHTML being set correctly, i have a div with id="lifecount", so i assume so?

Comment: life is 5 @FrankerZ

Comment: Where do you have the `lifecount` variable set? Can you display that code?

Comment: Right, i need a lifecount variable... whoops. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

With the code that you provided, the if statement will never be read, because you checked the case when life was equal to 1, and under that statement you also checked if the life was greater than 5. Basically when life = 1, you want to check if it is also >= 5.